# Adding a Click Event to a Button in a Different Class

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add a click event to a button that is defined in a different class.
Just a quick overview, this code creates a stack of cards with buttons on them and the buttons need click events.

The CardView class:

```
public class CardView : ContentView
{
    public Label Name { get; set; }
    public Image Photo { get; set; }
    public Label Location { get; set; }
    public Label Description { get; set; }
    public Button PassButton { get; set; }
    public Button FailButton { get; set; }


    public CardView()
    {
        // gives the card its black line
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        grid.Padding = 2;

        RelativeLayout view = new RelativeLayout();


        // box view as the background
        BoxView boxView1 = new BoxView
        {
            Color = Color.White,
            InputTransparent = true

        };

        view.Children.Add(boxView1,
            Constraint.Constant(0), Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
                return parent.Width;
            }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
                return parent.Height;
            })
        );


        // items image
        Photo = new Image()
        {
            InputTransparent = true,
            Aspect = Aspect.Fill
        };

        view.Children.Add(Photo,
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                double h = parent.Height * 0.80;
                return ((parent.Height - h) / 2) + 20;
            }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Width;
            }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return (parent.Height * 0.40);
            })
        );

        // items label
        Name = new Label()
        {
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            FontSize = 22,
            InputTransparent = true,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
        };

        view.Children.Add(Name,
            Constraint.Constant(10), Constraint.Constant(10),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Width;
            }),
            Constraint.Constant(28)
        );           

        // location description
        Location = new Label()
        {
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            FontSize = 18,
            InputTransparent = true
        };

        view.Children.Add(Location,
            Constraint.Constant(30), Constraint.Constant(40),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Width;
            }),
            Constraint.Constant(28)
        );

        //Image[] stars = new Image[5];

        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            Spacing = 2
        };         

        view.Children.Add(stack,
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Width - 90; // 
            }),
            Constraint.Constant(40)); //40

        // bottom label
        Description = new Label()
        {
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            FontSize = 16,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            InputTransparent = true
        };

        view.Children.Add(
            Description,
            Constraint.Constant(0),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return (parent.Height / 2f) + 30;
            }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Width;
            }),
            Constraint.Constant(40)
        );

        // camera button
        Button camera = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Camera",

            InputTransparent = true
        };

        view.Children.Add(camera,
                Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                {
                    return (parent.Width / 2f) - (camera.Width / 2f);
                }),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                {
                    return parent.Height - 70;
                })
                );



        PassButton = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Pass",
        };

        view.Children.Add(PassButton,Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent)=> 
                                    {
                                        return (parent.Width / 8f) - (PassButton.Width / 4f);
                                    }),
                                    Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                                    {
                                        return parent.Height - 70;
                                    })                                        
                                    );

        FailButton = new Button()
        {
            Text = "Fail",
        };


        view.Children.Add(FailButton, Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
        {
            return (parent.Width *(3/ 4f)) - (FailButton.Width / 4f);
        }),
        Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
        {
            return parent.Height - 70;
        })
        );


        grid.Children.Add(view);

        Content = grid;
    }
}
```

This class is used as sort of a template for the entire deck.
In another class multiple instances of the CardView class are created to make the deck of cards.
The creation of the cards is working fine.

So in the CardStackView (in the constructor) the deck is created:

```
 public CardStackView()
    {
        RelativeLayout view = new RelativeLayout();

        // create a stack of cards
        for (int i = 0; i < NumCards; i++) // 
        {
            var card = new CardView();                
            cards[i] = card;
            card.InputTransparent = true;
            card.IsVisible = false;


            view.Children.Add(
                card,
                Constraint.Constant(0),
                Constraint.Constant(0),
                Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                {
                    return parent.Width;
                }),

                Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                {
                    return parent.Height;
                })
            );
        }

        this.BackgroundColor = Color.Azure;

        this.Content = view;

    }
```

Is it possible to add click events/tapgestures to the buttons in the CardView class (PassButton and FailButton) in the constructor of the CardStackView when the deck is being created?
They kind of need to be added here given the nature of the rest of the CardStackView. There is a lot going on and its not feasible to reorganise the code at this point.
Is it even possible to do this?

Also things I have tried. 
I tried using the instance of the CardView in the for loop to access the button and add the events but this simply did nothing.
i.e `card.PassButton.Clicked += clickEvent`.

Any ideas? Or even if it is possible?

Comment: Dude! What a mess, huh?!

Comment: Im not sure what you are confused about.
The card view class creates a single card, the card stack view creates multiple cards. Can a click or tap event be added while the cards are being created?

Comment: I got it. I'm answering right now. I'm struggling with english, sorry. I mentioned it because this solution looks very unnecessarily complex to me. Despite this, I'm giving some possibilities =)

Comment: Not a problem! I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go.

I think that buttons, labels and image inside the `CardView` can be private variables, so you can deal with it in a more controlled way (the outside class should not change the position of the button inside your card, for example)

There's a lot of ways to do that. I thought 2 ways given your code structure:

**- 1 Encapsulating the event handler definition**

You can create a method in your `CardView` like:

```
public class CardView : ContentView
{
    // Your stuffs

    public void AddPassButtonClickedEvent(EventHandler handler)
    {
        if(handler != null)
            PassButton.Clicked += handler;
    }

    // Your stuffs
}
```

Outside the class, you will use it like:

```
var cardView = new CardView();
cardView.AddPassButtonClickedEvent((sender, args) => 
{
    // Do something
});
```

**- 2 Exposing your own event**

You can create your own events (or commands) at the `CardView` class and always asign the clicked event of the button. Like this:

```
public class CardView : ContentView
{
    // Your stuffs

    public event EventHandler MyPassButtonClickedEvent;

    public CardView()
    {
        // Instantiate your PassButton
        PassButton.Clicked += OnPassButtonClicked;
    }

    protected void OnPassButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MyPassButtonClickedEvent?.Invoke(object, args);
    }

    // Your stuffs
}
```

Again, you can use it outside this way:

```
class Fake
{
    CardView cardView;

    public Fake()
    {
        cardView = new CardView();
        cardView.MyPassButtonClickedEvent += MyHandler;
    }

    void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgus args)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet. Give me 5 mins while I implement these.

Comment: All right. Let me know if it works for you or if I can help in anything else =)

Comment: Sorry mate, but these dont seem to be working. I tried both but neither fire off. I put a debug in both and also tried using a break point in the events and it doesnt trigger it them.

Comment: Did you changed the button property to variable?

Comment: In the first approach, you put the breakpoint inside the method "`AddPassButtonClickedEvent`" and it was not hit?

Comment: Right so first off, I hadn't changed the buttons to variables, now I have.
Second after this change they still dont work.
I put Debug.writeLine in both of them and break points and they dont seem to fire

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157991/discussion-between-diego-rafael-souza-and-user3355961).

Comment: I'm suspecting the issue is outside the `CardView` class, once the method you've created as suggested is not being called...

Comment: I still havent been able to figure it out. I will let you know if I figure out why its not. But for now im still stuck